# Identify department on IVR (incoming call)

Tags: twilio, ivr

Ive built an IVR using twilio where 3 of the 4 departments forward to the same number. Is there any way to identify what department the incoming call is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

There is a whisper capability of the TwiML Number noun you could use, to pre-announce this to the called party before they are connected.

TwiML Number Noun
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url